# Unsafe connection after changing rules in .htaccess

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to set rules to change the URL from page `contact.php` to `contact` but the website now show unsafe connection in the main page but not on other pages.

This is the rule i used:

```
RewriteRule ^contact(.[A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ contact.php?=$1
```

While i still haven't set this clean URL yet, it's strange the website isn't using a secure connection anymore.

The link is [here](http://www.greatrailwayjourneys.net). Even if i clear the rule it is still unsecure and even if you write https:// in the URL, after navigating through other pages and back to the main page again it is not secure anymore.

Can you give me insight from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked your site. For every absolute URL you need to have https and not http as the protocol or use relative URLs.
So please check your HTML a-tags.
To also have the main site in https you should add another rewrite rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

Another thing is to fix the current contact regex to:

```
RewriteRule ^contact([.A-Za-z0-9-]*)/?$ contact.php?=$1
```

Comment: Kingson, many thanks. I'm using a constant with the site root URL in constants.php when needed but forgot to set an absolute https path in the menu.php. It was strange that the link i wrote used to go to a secure connection but not after writing some rules in the htaccess. As far as the rewrite rule goes, there's always a dot or comma lost somewhere :)

Answer (score 0):

This may not be answering you question directly, but when I need to change a url i use javascript. You can try...

```
var obj = { Title: 'Contact Us', Url: '/contact'};
history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
```

This would allow the browser to see the page as intended from the server and just show the url.

Comment: Thanks. I wrote the dot on the left of the brackets but solved it now with Kingson answer, but thanks anyway.